# Java byte array to Postgres JSONB

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there an elegant way to store java's byte array in postgres as JSONB column?

Let's say i have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Lond id;

    @Column(name="json_data")
    private byte[] jsonData;

    // getters and setters
}
```

So `json_data` in `my_table` is a column of type JSONB.

I use JPA and Hibernate as a provider. I have no problems with reading data, but when it comes to writing it treats `byte[]` as `bytea` (which makes sense). Can i somehow point it to JSONB instead?

If there's no easy way, what alternatives do i have?  I know that do that by registering Hibernate's UserType, but i'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you treat the JSON as a `String` in Java? Converting that to `byte[]` does not really make sense to me

Comment: JSON is a *data exchange* format that many environments can easily produce and interpret, not an efficient storage mechanism. Why do you want to use `jsonb` in the first place?

Comment: Agreed with your point. Personally i don't like the way it is used but in my case there's no alternatives.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what benefits it will give me?